# Nesting redux form fields for grouped validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form, redux-form-validators

Is the below considered a valid use of redux-form Fields?

```jsx
const ValidatedFieldGroup = (props) => {
  const {meta: {touched, error}} = props

  return (
    <div className={touched && error ? 'has-error' : ''}>
      <Field name="one" .... />
      <Field name="two" .... />
    </div>
  )
}

const MyMainComponent = (props) => {
  return <Field name="twofields"
                component={ValidatedFieldGroup}
                validate={myValidator} .... />
}

const myValidator = (value, allValues) => {
  return (
    allValues.one === "pretend-this-is-valid" && allValues.two === "pretend-this-is-valid"
  ) ? undefined : 'One of the fields is invalid - sort it out!'
}
```

A 'valueless' parent Field is implemented solely to hook into the sync field level validation pipeline. The props of this component can then be used to alter the UI / state of it's children (which in turn contain some RF Fields implementing the actual form values)

Real-world example = assume there are a group of five check boxes... if at least TWO of them are not checked then they should ALL be wrapped in a 'red bordered' div.

In seems to work thus far, but I am conscious that there may be an easier / better / correct way to achieve the same result or that I could in fact be setting myself up for future troubles!!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Although this work-around results in the desired UI (namely, a single `div` with the correct `class`), you'll end up with three fields in the redux-form store, `one`, `two`, and `twofields`, which seems undesirable. Presumably, you'll never do anything with the field `twofields` on the backend, since it's only used for presentation. This goes against the idea that the `redux-form` store should map to the fields in your backend (DB, or whatever...).

You could instead use the [Fields](https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/docs/api/fields.md/) component, so that you only register the `one` and `two` fields, which is more consistent:

```
import { Fields, ...} from "redux-form";

const renderValidatedFields = fields => {
    const { one, two } = fields;
    const showError = (one.meta.touched && one.meta.error) || (two.meta.touched && two.meta.error);
    return ( 
       <div className={showError ? 'has-error' : ''}>
          <input {...one.input} type="checkbox" />
          <input {...two.input} type="checkbox" />
       </div>
    )
}        

export default MyMainFieldComponent = props => {
    return <Fields names={["one", "two"]} component={renderValidatedFields} />
}
```

Then put your validator against `redux-form` in the config:

```
import React from "react";
import { reduxForm } from "redux-form";

import MyMainFieldComponent from "./MyMainFieldComponent";

// validate the whole form
const myValidator = values => {
    const msg = "Invalid selection.";
    const errors = {};

    if (!values.one) {
        errors.one = msg;
    }

    if (!values.two) {
        errors.two = msg;
    }

    return errors;
}

...

let MyForm = props => {
    ...
    return (
        <form ...>
            <MyMainFieldComponent />
        </form>
    )
}

MyForm = reduxForm({
    ...,
    validate: myValidator
})(MyForm);

export default MyForm;
```

Comment: Thanks @inostia, great and easy to understand example of the `Fields` component which I had previously overlooked. Given that the value of `twofields` in my example never has its value set and will only ever appear in the `redux-form` store as a registered field, is it still considered bad practice? My concern with the use of `Fields` is that there is no ability to specify validation at the field level... adding the ability validate at the form level would complicate our implementation quite significantly.

Comment: It feels icky to me to register a new Field component solely for the purpose of presentation, but to each his own. If you really need to do _field_ level validation, rather than form validation, maybe take a look at https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/docs/api/fieldarray.md/#-code-fieldarray-code-. This will namespace your field, eg `myCheckboxes`. You can perform validation on the `<FieldArray />` component. But I'm not sure if it's worth-it to you.

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that you'd need to set errors on each individual field with this method?  In the OP's use case, it seems more appropriate to have a "global" error message that isn't related to the individual fields, since a certain number of them need to be checked.

Comment: In that case you can use the global error prop that's passed to your form: https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/docs/api/props.md/#-code-error-any-code-